# Function with compact support whose iterated antiderivatives also have compact support

Tags: real-analysis

**Notation:** If $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, let us denote $If\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ its indefinite integral from $0$, i.e., $(If)(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, and iteratively $I^{k+1}f = I(I^k f)$.

**Remark:** If $f$ is a continuous function with support contained in the open interval $]0,1[$ then $If$ has support contained in $]0,1[$ iff $(If)(1) = 0$.

**Main question:** Does there exist a $C^\infty$ function $f$ with support contained in the open interval $]0,1[$ such that $I^k f$ has support contained in $]0,1[$ for every $k\geq 0$, or, equivalently, $(I^k f)(1) = 0$ for all $k\geq 0$?

**Equivalent formulation:** Does there exists a sequence $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of $C^\infty$ functions each with support contained in the open interval $]0,1[$, such that $f_{k-1}$ is the derivative of $f_k$?

**Weaker question:** Does there at least exist a continuous function $f$ with the properties demanded in the main question?

**Stronger question:** Does there exist a $C^\infty$ function $f$ with compact support, whose Fourier transform vanishes identically on a nontrivial interval?

(A positive answer to the latter would imply a positive answer to the main question: rescale the function so its support is contained in $]0,1[$, multiply it appropriately so its Fourier transform vanishes in a neighborhood of $0$, and observe that the Fourier transform of $I^k f$ is, up to constants, $\xi^k$ times that of $f$.)

**Edit:** Before someone points out that the identically zero function fits the bill, I should add that I want my functions to not vanish identically.

Comment: I think the stronger assertion should be false by Paley-Wiener,

Comment: @PaulK: Something along the lines of “if a function has compact support, its Fourier transform is analytic, so it cannot vanish identically on a nontrivial interval without vanishing identically”? Indeed, this seems to work. It might even answer the original question by imposing all derivatives of the Fourier transform to vanish at the origin…

Comment: You might be right that this could also works for your original question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not possible even for $f$ only measurable and bounded. Indeed,
$$(I^kf)(x)=\int_{x_0=0<x_1<...<x_k=x}f(x_1)dx_1...dx_k=\int_0^xf(x_1)\left(\int_{x_1<...<x_k=x}dx_2...dx_k\right)dx_1$$
Now since
$$\int_{a<y_1...<y_k<b}dy_1...dy_k=(b-a)^k\int_{0<y_1...<y_k<1}dy_1...dy_k=\frac{(b-a)^k}{k!}$$
we get : 
$$(I^kf)(1)=\int_0^1f(y)\frac{(1-y)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}dy.$$
If this was vanishing for any $k$ then for all polynomial $P$ we would get : 
$$\int_0^1f(y)P(y)dy=0$$
and therefore $f$ is $0$ almost everywhere.

The hypothesis that $f$ is bounded is probably not necessary (in fact if $f$ is locally integrable, $I^1f$ is bounded continuous and we can apply the previous argument to $I^1f$.)